# MVC3 razor return current view

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've got a actionlink in my master page `_Layout` That when pressed, changes the layout of my menu. But I don't want the current Content of my page to change.

How can I accomplish this with MVC3 razor *without* using javascript?

I'm guessing it will be something along the lines of:

- Button is clicked postback happens
- Set some value so changed menu state persists
- Return previous view

Especially the "return previous view" part perplexes me, could someone explain how to accomplish this?

Comment: `HttpContext` will have all the information you need to persist the view (assuming no data was submitted).  However, if you're partially updating the page I have to ask why you don't use AJAX/PartialViewResult and only update the menu portion?

Comment: Need some clarification, specifically when you say "But I don't want the current Content of my page to change" do you mean that you don't want to lose any form field values when the page posts back?

Comment: @Heather I want to make changes only to the master page part, without updating anything where `@RenderBody` is.

Comment: @BradChristie I want to make it work without JavaScript first, add javascript later. Seems to me that this is the correct way of making a robust website. Also, I don't know what a partialViewResult is, checking it out now.

Comment: @ProgrammerAtWork: a partial page refresh is the epitome of AJAX. Without it you _have_ to do a full page refresh (unless you want to get in to frames).

Comment: @BradChristie I don't mind doing a full page refresh, as long as the refresh returns the page to the same view.

Answer (score 2):

In your controller override OnActionExecuting:

```
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["MenuLayoutName"] != null && IsValidMenuLayoutName(filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["MenuLayoutName"] != null))
            ViewBag.MenuLayoutName = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["MenuLayoutName"];
    }
```

In your _Layout.cshtml when you render the menu, look at the ViewBag.MenuLayoutName to decide which menu to use. The most efficient way is to simply create partial views so you can render the menu as follows:

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial(ViewBag.MenuLayoutName); }
```

However, take note of the call to IsValidMenuLayoutName! Otherwise people could put the name of any valid partial view in there and get it rendered where you expect your menu to appear.

In your links where you want to allow the user to select the various menu layouts, change your link to the page to specify the name of the layout to use.

```
<a href="/Index?MenuLayoutName=RedLayout">Use Red Menu</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a VERY primitive approach, you can create buttons essentially linking to itself:

```
<a href="@(Request.RawUrl)?menu=foo">Foo Menu</a>
<a href="@(Request.RawUrl)?menu=bar">Bar Menu</a>
```

(Or use logic to show either/or based on what's visible) Then modify your `_Layout.cshtml` to render what's provided:

```
@{
  String menu = (String)Request.Params["menu"] ?? "foo";
  if (menu == "foo"){
    /* Foo menu render */
  } else {
    /* bar menu render */
  }
}
```

Then it's just a round-trip to the same URL. Again, if they landed on the page via POSTed information, you'll lose that. Also, I didn't add logic to test if `menu` already existed in the request, but you should.